# Does jayway maven plugin option <manifestVersioncode> really works for Android app?

Tags: android, maven, build, version

I've got Android application, which is mavenized and using couple of profiles for different customers. I am using also jayway maven plugin to configure some stuff, including package name (able to differentiate apps in Google Play), release mode and also version code, which should be different for each maven profile. I've noticed that

```
<manifestVersioncode>
```

doesn't work for me. It always takes version code from Android manifest xml file instead. 
I found out by having this code in the app, checking in first activity:

```
PackageInfo pInfo;
try {
    pInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
    int version = pInfo.versionCode;
    Log.d(TAG, "version code: " + version);
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Does anybody have same experience and were able to you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

as I've learnt, it has to be done properly, it works now

```
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>update-manifest</id>
        <goals>
            <goal>manifest-update</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <manifest>
                <versionCode>2</versionCode>
            </manifest>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
```